# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" when adding items into a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, gdi+

I am kind of confused here,
I have an array of `bytes` that i convert into a `string`
then split the `string` and add the split to an `ArrayList`
then add the `ArrayList` into a `ListView`.
It used to work but now it doesnt, im not sure why.

```
//bytes to string.
string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);

// clear arraylist and listbox.
ItemDetails.Clear();
listBox1.Items.Clear();

// split the string and add the split into the arraylist.
ItemDetails.AddRange(str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

// Add arraylist into listbox. It throws the generic error here:
listBox1.Items.AddRange(ItemDetails.ToArray());
```

Exception Details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.UpdateMaxItemWidth(Object item, Boolean removing)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddInternal(Object item)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRangeInternal(ICollection items)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(Object[] items)
       at ItemTypeEditor.FrmMain.loadItems() in c:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\ItemTypeEditor\ItemTypeEditor\FrmMain.cs:line 254
       at ItemTypeEditor.FrmMain.FrmMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\ItemTypeEditor\ItemTypeEditor\FrmMain.cs:line 219
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I realize there is not a lot of info here, so let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Is there anything unusual in the string? Non keyboard characters for example?

Comment: not that i know of, its a lot of text. but ill check, but it seems to work with a hardcoded string.

Comment: No there is just normal chars in the string. but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to recreate control. Maybe designer code in Initialize() is damaged. It looks like listbox could not update width for items, because of measuring string fails.

Could you post code from Initialize which describe listBox1?

Comment: this seemed to work. if i cut the control and paste it, it does not work. but if i delete it and recreate it then it works.